# Creating two-staved ossia in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

How can I create an ossia in lilypond with two staves (for piano). I want the ossia to be smaller in size than the regular music and if possible have the dotted line connecting it to the actual music exactly as shown in the attached image (Liszt-Reminiscences de Norma for reference). Thank you very much.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use this as a starting point:

```
\defineBarLine "|" #'("|" "" "!")

\new StaffGroup \with {
  \override SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f
} << 
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = main \with { 
      \override BarLine.allow-span-bar = ##f
    } \relative c' {
      \key c \minor
      % c4 d es f   in case you need music before the ossia starts
      <<
        { c4 d es f  c4 d es f }

        \new PianoStaff << 
          \new Staff \with {
            \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
            alignAboveContext = #"main"
            fontSize = #-3
            \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(magstep -3)
            \override StaffSymbol.thickness = #(magstep -3)
            \override BarLine.allow-span-bar = ##f
          } \relative c' { 
            \key c \minor
            c4 d es f  c4 d es f 
          }
          \new Staff \with {
            \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
            alignAboveContext = #"main"
            fontSize = #-3
            \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(magstep -3)
            \override StaffSymbol.thickness = #(magstep -3)
          } \relative c {
            \key c \minor
            \clef bass
            c4 d es f  c4 d es f 
          }
        >> 
      >>
      c d es f
    }
    \new Staff \relative c {
      \key c \minor
      \clef bass
      c4 d es f  c4 d es f  c4 d es f 
    }
  >>
>>
```

As for the double-staff ossia, you can actually add as much staves as ossia as you wish. You can also group them together. This is shown in the code above.

With `\defineBarLine "|" #'("|" "" "!")` you can override the standard bar line `|`, so that it becomes dashed only between the staves. In this case, because the left-hand and the right-hand staves are not connected, it could be a simple solution in your case.

The above code produces the following:

[image]

Comment: You said that the dotted lines should look “exactly” as in the given example. But as you can see, the line at the beginning of the system in the LilyPond rendering above is not dotted or dashed. Unfortunately, modifications of this `SystemStartBar` are quite complicated, so I would suggest you leave it that way.